# How to make SCons export compile commands including flags pointing to a conda virtual environment?

Tags: c++, anaconda, conda, scons, clangd

I'm working on a C++ project that is built with SCons. I installed SCons using my system's package manager. The project has some dependencies that I installed into a virtual environment using conda. I followed the SCons [documentation](https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/ch27.html) to export a `compile_commands.json`.

When I activate the project's conda environment, then run scons, everything compiles fine and a `compile_commands.json` is created. However, the exported compile commands are missing `-I` or `-isystem` flags that point to the `include/` directory of the conda environment.

My editor (vim/Ycm) relies on clangd for linting and semantic completion, clangd relies on the exported compile commands and is not aware of the conda virtual environment. How can I make SCons export the required flags so that clangd can find the dependencies headers?

(For comparison, a different project that is set up the exact same way but using CMake exports compile commands with `-isystem` flags to the conda environment.)

Comment: Can you provide a simple reproducer for this? Hard to know what the cause is without one.  Also you may want to bring this directly to the scons users mailing list or discord server.

Comment: There is some virtualenv support in SCons, don't think this is heavily used but might be worth a try: https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html#opt-enable-virtualenv

Comment: Two potential things to try: 1) Launch your editor from inside the virtual environment. This would likely handle the case where the include directories are contained in environment variables (e.g. `CFLAGS`), since editors typically pass through env vars when launching clangd. 2) Use the `--query-driver` option to clangd as described [here](https://clangd.llvm.org/troubleshooting#cant-find-standard-library-headers-map-stdioh-etc). This would handle the case where the includes in question are built into the compiler used for building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got SCons to export the correct compile commands by adding the line

```
env.Append(CPPPATH= ['/path/to/my/conda/env/include'])
```

to the `SConstruct` file. I assume the reason for the compilation working even without this line is that the compiler is installed in the same conda environment.